# Decimal type in Go and Postgresql with gorm

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

So i'm creating an API and I needed to store the price of something.

I'm using gorm and gormigrate for my database migration. 
I'm just wondering what proper type should I use for storing decimals. I've red somewhere that I shouldn't use floats when storing currencies.

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Name        string `json:"name" gorm:"not null"`
    Description string `json:"description" gorm:"null"`
    Price <what type should be here> `json:"price"`
}
```

Comment: I have used github.com/shopspring/decimal for money values.

Comment: can you please show an example of how you used it? gorm is throwing an error when i do automigrate

Comment: Sorry, I don't use grom myself and thus don't have any experience using shopspring/decimal with it...

Comment: @ain, oh, btw thanks for suggesting the package. greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ain, nice package! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, based on the suggestion of @ain, I used shopspring/decimal. But it's giving me an error when I do automigrate.

It turns out that I only needed to set the type to `numeric` using a gorm tag to make it work:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Name        string `json:"name" gorm:"not null"`
    Description string `json:"description" gorm:"null"`
    Price decimal.Decimal `json:"price" gorm:"type:numeric"`
}
```